# How to run a gradle build using buildspec.yml

Tags: gradle, build, yaml

Is there any way to run a gradle build using buildspec.yml file. buildspec.yml file contains a list of gradle build commands.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see the relevant help-center article

Answer (score 10):

Yes its possible, PFB buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
   commands:
     - echo Entering install phase...
     - echo Nothing to do now
  build:
    commands:
     - echo Build started on `date`
     - gradle build
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - 'build/libs/*.jar'
```

For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html